# Specifying valid inheritance for templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

In Java, when using genericism, you can specify what types are allowed to be used by doing something like this:

```java
public class A<T inherits B>
{
   public A(T e);
}
```

If the semantics is wrong I'm sorry, I haven't written Java in quite a few years.

Is there a way to do so with templates in C++, and if so how? From what I have seen in my research so far, people seem to be doing it through the use of extra arguments, but that seems like a worse solution than using like a `static_assert`.

Something like this I guess:

```cpp
template<typename T : std::vector>
class A
{
    A(T t) {}
};
```

In the example above `T` inherits from `std::vector` and as such allows for all potential classes that extend the capabilities of the STL vector class

Comment: `static_assert` was added in C++11. The solutions you saw might have been intended for C++03.

Comment: requiring inheritance from a base is rather untypical. Usually you only care about what operations the type supports, if it quacks like a duck then it is a duck, while you rather require it to have a label on its forhead saying "I am a duck" otherwise it isn't a duck, no matter how duck-like it is

Comment: Why just `std::vector`? What if someone wants to use `std::list`? Is there any reason they shouldn't be able to use `std::list` if it supports all of the operations that `A` is going to use? What if someone writes their own compatible container? Why can't they use that?

Comment: don't try to translate directly what you know from java generics to c++ templates, they are completely different worlds

Comment: btw also (publicly) inheriting from `std::vector` is rarely a good idea (or never?), standard containers are not meant to be inherited from, though one can write a container that has similar interface and can be used with all algorithms that also work for a `std::vector`